# 5 dead hard drives in a span of 2 months - what should I be checking?

Tags: raid, hp

So we got a nice new HP DL380 server with a fancy RAID card about one year ago.

2 months ago a hard drive failed. Thank goodness for RAID5... except that the RAID card only sort of worked and the machine hard reset. After fvck it came back up.

6 weeks ago another drive fails. Machine hard reset again, came back up.

4 weeks ago another drive fails. Machine hard resets. The data center puts a new drive in, and the new drive fails. Replace that drive. After a fvck it comes back up.

This morning, yet another drive (this is the 5th drive now, for those who are counting) reports "SMART imminent failure".

Needless to say, we've moved everything off this server so that it's not in use anymore.

Can anyone think of anything that could be going on to cause this sort of scenario? I find it hard to believe that there could be *this many* bad hard drives. Is the RAID card toasting hard drives? Power supply issue?

Comment: This is probably a good case for contacting the vendor. Are there are any firmware updates available? Are the disks from different lots? I would assume so because of the amount of time which has passed, but you never know.

Comment: Please give the generation of the DL380 server.

Comment: Maybe the datacenter isn't replacing the failed drives with new drives. Maybe they're using old drives that have been sitting on a shelf or drives that were decommissioned from other servers or refurbished drives purchased online. Have you asked them where they're getting the replacement drives from?

Answer (score 2):

1. Controller failure
2. bad controller firmware
3. faulty drives supplied by the hoster (some of the less reputable ones tend to do that)
4. bad combo of disk and controller firmware

Comment: I would consider Power Supply as well

Comment: + Environment, temperature, no grounding, static electricity, magnetic field sources

Comment: The list could go on and on :)